# how to configure kdevelop projects toolbar to hide certain files?

Tags: kdevelop

I have a project that usues autotools and I also need coverage reports by gcov, which generates files in the same folders where the sources are.

My problem is that my "Projects" toolbar shows all `.gcno` files and all make targets (which would be about 30 per folder).

**Is there any way to configure `kdevelop` not to show all make targets and not to show files with certain extensions (e.g. `.gcno` files)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDevelop 4.6 has a feature that allows exactly that:
http://milianw.de/blog/kdevelop-project-filters

You can add `*.gcno` as project filter and those files won't show up on the Project View.